# Can you change the caption font size using Pandas styling?

Tags: pandas

I am trying to change the font size of a caption using the pandas styling API. Is this possible?

Here is what I have so far:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)

df.style.set_caption("Some Caption")
```

Appreciate any input.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try this:

```
df.style.set_caption("Some Caption").set_table_styles([{
    'selector': 'caption',
    'props': [
        ('color', 'red'),
        ('font-size', '16px')
    ]
}])
```